# XCode 5.0.1 crashes - cannot open any project

Tags: xcode, macos, crash, osx-mavericks

I have an updated MAC OS Mavericks, with DP5 and newly installed XCode 5.0.1. XCode crahses - I cannot create a new project and also cannot open an existing one. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Repare the rights in disk utility.
2. Reset PRAM.
3. If this doesn't help redownload Xcode.

Comment: Could you please write steps. I am new to MAC :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

1. Repair Rights in Disk Utility
2. Reboot
3. Open Xcode
4. Open project

   - Project opens as expected! Whoot.

Answer (score 0):

Just update to DP7 and it will work!